# atomic increment of long variable?

Tags: java, concurrency

if a long variable is declared as :-

**private volatile long counter = 0;**

now if i increment it using pre-increment operator, then would the operation be atomic ?

if yes, then will it be more efficient than `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong` object's increment ??

Comment: using a pre-increment operator doesn't change the fact that incrementing is a non-atomic operation.

Comment: as mre said, its not atomic. what happens (basically) is that the value gets loaded, then incremented and then the incremented value will be stored again. thus it is not atomic. have a look at [this](http://madbean.com/2003/mb2003-44/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`volatile` keyword only solves [visibility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/) problem. You have to use `AtomicLong` or `synchronized` method/block for atomicity ([Atomicity in concurrent programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28programming%29)).

One more article that came out today: [Demonstrating when volatile is required](http://java.dzone.com/articles/demonstrating-when-volatile)

Comment: +1 I learned a new term, "Atomicity".  I probably would have said Atomicness or Atomictudeinous.  :-)

Comment: @user949300 Atomicity is a proper word used in concurrent and dbms world

Comment: @Pangea Is it just `visibility` only or `ordering` also ?

Answer (score 3):

The pre-increment operator is *not* atomic. Also, incrementing a `volatile long` is likely to be less efficient than using `AtomicLong` on almost all platforms, because the latter is supported by hardware.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No.  You will need to synchronize the method that increments counter, or, preferably, use an AtomicLong.

For the record, ++ operators are not atomic *even on integers*.

Answer (score 2):

A volatile variable is not the same as an atomic variable.

For volatile variables, the java compiler will attempt to minimize shuffling commands around for the sake of efficiency (don't ask me the details of that.. ), to avoid concurrency problems.

Atomic variables are explicitly made for atomic operations, like in your case incrementing a variable atomically.