# issue with volatile in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand how volatile works in java. Here is simple program which i have tried

```
public class ThreadTryTry extends Thread {

    static InstanceClass iCLass = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadTryTry tt1 = new ThreadTryTry();
        ThreadTryTry tt2 = new ThreadTryTry();
        tt1.setName("thread 1");
        tt2.setName("thread 2");
        iCLass = new InstanceClass();
        tt1.start();

        // Thread.sleep(1000);
        tt2.start();

        // Thread.sleep(1000);
        iCLass.display();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("x= " + iCLass.x + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("y= " + iCLass.y + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        iCLass.x++;
        iCLass.y++;
    }  
}

class InstanceClass {

    volatile int x = 0;
    volatile int y = 0;

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("x= " + x + " y= " + y);
    }
}
```

Output is as expected

```
x= 0 thread 1
y= 0 thread 1
x= 1 thread 2
y= 1 thread 2
x= 2 y= 2
```

If I remove sleep statement I am getting random output like

```
x= 0 y= 0
x= 0 thread 2
y= 0 thread 2
x= 0 thread 1
y= 1 thread 1
```

my expectation is no matter whether thread sleep or not, output should be same as the initial one.

i have gone through other questions on Volatile but couldn't find out what is issue with my program. doesn't the volatile guarantee that the variable will be read and written back to memory and other thread should see the latest value of variable.

Comment: "Volatile" is not "atomic". Both threads read from `x`, increment their local copy, then write the incremented value.

Comment: Answered also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102761/atomic-increment-of-long-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No issue here.

### What *can be* happening?

A possible execution on an absolute (and fake) timeline:

```
t1 starts
t2 starts
main displays
t2 prints x=0
t2 prints y=0
t1 prints x=0
t2 increments x
t2 increments y
t1 prints y=1
```

You have no *happen-before* relationship between main, t1, and t2 are they are all concurrent so the order things happen can vary.